# Why is the volume of a cube with fractional units smaller?

Tags: geometry

So the volume of a cube is `V = l x w x h`. 
So a cube with sides 2 is `2 x 2 x 2 = 8`

Ok, so now we have a cube with sides 1/4. So `1/4 x 1/4 x 1/4 = 1/64`.
Why is the volume smaller than the side lengths in this case?
`8 > 2` but `1/64 < 1/4`

Put another way, let's say the cube has side lengths of 1/4 foot. That is the same as 3 inches.
If you calculate the volume of the cube in inches, you get 27 inches cubed. But if you calculate it in feet
you get 1/64 feet cubed. `27 inches > 1/64 foot`. Why aren't they equal?

Comment: Because you can fit $64$ of these cubes into a unit cube. Whereas the side length of these small cubes are still only a quarter of the side length of the unit cube

Comment: $27$ *cubic* inches = $1/64$ *cubic* foot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a cube with a side length of $1m$. Its volume is $1m^3$.  Written in centimetres, its side length is $100cm$, and as such, its volume is $1000000cm^3$. But $1\neq 1000000$. How can this be so?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare generalized volumes in spaces of different dimension.  It makes no sense whatsoever, for instance, to say that an area of $1\ m^2$ is "larger" than a volume of $.00000001\ m^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a > 0$.

When is $a^2 > a$? Well, since $a$ is positive, you can divide by $a$ both sides of the inequality and get $a > 1$. And conversely for positive $a$, if $a > 1$ then you can multiply both sides by $a$ and get $a^2 > a$. So the square of a number is greater than the number if and only if the number is greater than 1. Cubes and higher powers work the same way.

When is $a^2 < a$? Again, since $a$ is positive, you can divide both sides by $a$ and get $a < 1$. And conversely for positive $a$, if $a < 1$ then you can multiply both sides by $a$ and get $a^2 < a$. So the square of a number is less than the number if and only if the number is less than 1. Cubes and higher power work the same way.